# python check if elements in a list of substrings are contained in a dataframe column

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe with products, and I want to check if the elements of a list of strings are contained in each dataframe row.

I have:

```
df
       Name
'Teejel gel 1*1 Tube 15 G'
'Glandosan spray 1*1 50 ML'
'Pantoprazol sandoz cpr.gastro-res 40mg 1*28 blist.'
```

and a list with several pharmaceutical forms I want to extract:

`list_forms=['gel','pills', 'spray', 'cpr.gastro-res','cpr']`

I basically want to have:

```
df
       Name                                      Form
'Teejel gel 1*1 Tube 15 G'                     ['gel']
'Glandosan spray 1*1 50 ML'                    ['spray']
'Pantoprazol sandoz cpr.gastro-res 40mg 1*28'  ['cpr.gastro-res','cpr']
```

What's the more eficient way to do this, without using for loops?

Comment: First, submit your attempt to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Try looking at [How to check if Pandas column has value from list of String?](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-pandas-column-has-value-from-list-of-string/amp/)

Comment: @Pedro Domingues  last line is [cpr.gastro-res]? If so, I can do it using a list generator (it's faster than a loop).